# Entity framework didn't get expected connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following app.config in my database library project

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>    
    <contexts>
      <!-- type:(qualified context class name, assembly ) -->
      <context type="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXX.XXX" >
        <databaseInitializer type="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXX.XXX"/>
      </context>      
    </contexts>   
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">      
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXX" connectionString="Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=Money;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And I have a console project use this library. The problem is that it will connect to the localDB not the database I set in the library project app.config. Why?

If I set connection string in the console project's config then it works well, but it's not a good solution. Is possible to let the library project use it own config?

Comment: Can you show your DbContext class?

Comment: AFAIK , any config in class libraries are ignored at runtime. Only the start up config matters.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Thx, It helps a lot. By the way may I delete the config file in the library project?

Comment: yes. You can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always like that, the connectionstrings are in the config file of the start-up project. If you reference your database project in another project with a dll, and the connectionstring would be embedded in that project, how can you ever change it? That's the whole point of your config file in your start-up project, to configure the settings for THAT solution. 
If you really want to put the connectionstring in your database project (not recommended!) you can look into Embedded resources/define it as `const string`

You can do it like this in your DBContext class

```
public TestDB() : base("data source=x.x.x.x;initial catalog=DBName;
                        persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;
                        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework")
```